# Firebase loot system?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a very simple tap based MMO in Unity for iOS, with [Firebase for Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup) as a backend. At the end of a fight I want to generate a chest with random loot in it.

I am wondering if there is any way to do that randomization in Firebase, as to prevent someone from cheating and sending calls that they got some exotic loot every turn.

This could be as simple as calling a random record in my weapons table or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase developer here.

One possibility is that you can use ServerValue.TIMESTAMP to get the timestamp from the server and mod it once you get it locally.  (ServerValue.TIMESTAMP % 100).
You can then have a location in the database with both the timestamp along with the calculated loot.

Unfortunately this doesn't free you from having to run something out of the client.  But... instead of spending money and risking downtime on a live loot server, you can instead run a checking process periodically to scan for cheaters by recalculating the loot using the stored timestamp and ensuring the timestamp looks legit.

So.. right now your options are currently limited -- but please stay tuned - this is one of our most requested features.

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely what I was looking for. It didn't seem like there was a direct way using firebase but I atleast wanted to provide for sanity checks which this looks like it could do! Also if this type of feature does get made I will be very excited.

Comment: Please check out the newly released "Cloud Functions" which makes it easy to create a server side loot system.  

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/introducing-cloud-functions-for-firebase.html

With Cloud Functions, you can respond to a new write in the database to calculate loot server side and then write that data into a user/read-only section of your database.

Comment: This is so promising, I'm excited! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firebase does not include any random-selection features. You would need to implement this in some other way.